# A well pointed inclusion induces injection of pointed homotopy classes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Strom, 5.144 shows that there exists a short exact sequence of pointed sets
$$
0 \to [X,Y]\overset{\phi}\to \langle X,Y\rangle \to \pi_0(Y)\to 0
$$
where

1. $X$ is well-pointed, i.e. $*\to X$ is a cofibration;
2. $[X,Y]$ are pointed homotopy classes of maps $X\to Y$;
3. $\langle X,Y\rangle$ are free homotopy classes of maps $X\to Y$.

Hence $\phi$ is surjective as soon as $Y$ is path-connected.

> Is anything similar true in a generic model category, where
>
> 1. $(X,x) \in */{\cal M}$ is a pointed object such that $x : *\to X$ is a cofibration;
> 2. $[X,Y]=\text{ho}(*/{\cal M})(X,Y)$;
> 3. $\langle X,Y\rangle=\text{ho}({\cal M})(X,Y)$.